# how to use delete command in grid view for updation

Tags: asp.net

i have 3 web pages. admin,student and teacher. i have used grid view on each of this page.my table is having a column as 'status'.which is having default value 0. I want to update this value to 1 when i click on delete in gridview. I have written following code. But it is not working.pls help.

this is .aspx file code-

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TEMPRUJUConnectionString %>" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [login] WHERE ([username] = @username)" 
 DeleteCommand="UPDATE [login] SET [status]= 1 WHERE [id]=@id" 
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [login] ([name], [midname], [surname], [username], [password], [contact], [dob], [email], [address], [occupation], [ltype]) VALUES (@name, @midname, @surname, @username, @password, @contact, @dob, @email, @address, @occupation, @ltype)" 
 UpdateCommand="UPDATE [login] SET [name] = @name, [midname] = @midname, [surname] = @surname, [username] = @username, [password] = @password, [contact] = @contact, [dob] = @dob, [email] = @email, [address] = @address, [occupation] = @occupation, [ltype] = @ltype WHERE [Id] = @Id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
```

and this is my code behind-

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SNEHAL-PC\\SNEHAL1;Initial Catalog=TEMPRUJU;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    con.Open();
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    cmd=new SqlCommand("Update login set status=1 where id='" + GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + "'",con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

when you have `SqlDataSource` you have no need to implement `GridView1_RowDeleting`,

first you must tell to `SqlDataSource` that where it can find the value of `delete command` parametr(s), in your case `@id`... for this, you need to set `DataKeyNames` property on your `GridView` by database unique key field name, in your case `id`...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
```

then, to set delete command parameter on `SqlDataSource` you must tell that, find value of `@id` from `SelectedDataKey` property, from `GridView` like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TEMPRUJUConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand="UPDATE [login] SET [status]= 1 WHERE [id]=@id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and finaly, you need to, send a `Delete` command with your `gridView`, for this, you can `enable deleteing` on `gridview` control to add this `<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />` into your grid view markup, or you can `convert this field into a TemplateFiled` and create your own template with any control **_*which have*_** `CommandName` property, and set that property `(CommandName)` to keyword `Delete` like this :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete me"></asp:LinkButton>
```

this is a sample with `Template Field`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="UPDATE Profiles SET Age = Age+1 where id = @id" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Profiles">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and this is a sample with just `enable deleteing` :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="UPDATE Profiles SET Age = Age+1 where id = @id" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Profiles">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

i increment `age` in my sample by every delete command